# How to correctly set the zIndex of features within an OpenLayers vector layer?

Tags: openlayers, labeling, features, vector-layer, z-index

I initially add a vector layer from a GeoJSON file and label each feature:

```
var layer1 = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: new ol.source.Vector({
          url: './json_3573/country_names.geojson',
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        }),
        zIndex: 0,
        style: function(feature) {
            return [new ol.style.Style({
                zIndex: 0,
                image: new ol.style.Icon({
                  anchor: [0.5, 46],
                  anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                  anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                  src: './images/pin.png'
                }),
                text: new ol.style.Text({
                    scale: 1.1,
                    text: feature.get('sr_subunit').toUpperCase(),
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#4f4f4f'
                      }),
                    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                        color: '#fff',
                        width: 2
                    }),
                    padding: [12,12,12,12],
                })
            })];
        },
        rotateWithView: true,
        declutter: true
    }); 
map.addLayer(layer1);
```

When later adding another vector `'layer2'` with a higher zIndex = 5, the labels and markers from `layer1` overlay `layer2`, ie. the opposite of what I would expect.

```
var layer2 = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: './json_3573/200km_mesh_3573.geojson',
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    }),
    zIndex: 5,
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
            color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.98)'  
        })
    })
});

map.addLayer(layer2);
```

What is the correct way to render all the features and text labels within `layer1` below `layer2`?

Comment: It is because your labels are being decluttered.  You will need to render that layer separately by giving it a unique className https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10096

Comment: Ah ok, that fix sorted the problem. Thanks, Mike.